# rename variables in the middle of the scope

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style, rename

I want to change a variable name in middle of its scope for readability issue.

For example:

```
while(condition){
    std::vector<big_type> all_things;
    //some operation like pop_back is happing on all_things
    //now all_things contains just the good_things
    auto& good_things=all_things;
    //do some operation on good_things which is actually on all_things
}
```

I am doing this because I can not afford copying this vector.

Is this the right way to do it? I am afraid now that my will to make it more readable resulted in less readability. Any other suggestions?

**EDIT:**

The problem is like : getting all objects then filtering them. After that, working with the filtered object but I see it hard to name it all_things while it was filtered. In same time, I can not name it good_things before filtering. So, I was seeking a way of variable renaming.

Comment: I consider that as useless code obfuscation (you may put a comment `//all_things are good now` instead).

Comment: Well, nobody stops you from doing this. However, if you care about performance you may want to reconsider. By doing that you are introducing some additional aliasing that the compiler may have hard time figuring out. As a consequence it may not be able to apply same optimizations.

Comment: @DieterLücking thanks. it may be the only solution. However, I was seeking a code-based way to do it. mmmm commenting is part of the syntax so maybe you are right :)

Comment: I would just name it good_things to start with since that's what it's supposed to hold. Then you can add comments like `// inserting all things` `// filtering to remove bad things`.

Comment: @simpel01 I did not think about optimization ambiguity for the compiler.. good points thanks

Comment: If the responsibility of a variable changes in the middle of a function, you're doing something wrong. Consider splitting the two parts into separate functions. (Single Responsibility Principle)

Comment: @zenith it is something similar to Mohmmad Elghawi comment. Some kind of getting all objects then filtering them. After that, working with the filtered object but I see it hard to name it all_things while it was filtered. In same time, I can not name it good_things before filtering

Comment: I would do something like `good_things = filter(std::move(all_things), ...)` or similiar, where `filter` accepts this vector by value(so the caller can opt to copy or move). Or maybe something that accepts two iterators to the sequence being filtered, and one iterator to the beginning of where I want to place the results.

Comment: @CássioRenan due to the absence of direct solution ,yours seems to be the best way. You may  past it as an answer so I can accept. Thanks

Comment: You might be kind of prioritizing the things that won't be to your best interest in the future. When you come back to old functions years later, often the tripping points beyond the logic are the number of states/variables involved. Keeping track of which state is what involves a mental overhead. If you start introducing new ones solely for the documenting purpose of renaming things in the middle of a function, it might actually do more harm in the long run than good.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you definitely want to keep track of goodness bit it's better to write something like the following

```
template <class T> struct MaybeGood {
   T obj;
   bool good;
   MaybeGood (const T& o, bool g) : obj(o), good(g) {}
   MaybeGood (bool g) : good(g) {}
};
............
while(condition){
    MaybeGood<std::vector<big_type> > obj(false);
    //work with obj.obj to make it good
    obj.good = true; //both for debugging and for the readability
    //enjoy the object :-)
}
```